# Calculating the 10001st prime number

Tags: java

I want to calculate the 10001st prime number as in problem [7 euler project](http://projecteuler.net/problem=7). This is what I have done:

```
int i=0;
int counter=2;
while (i<=10001){
    counter++;
    if (Helper.isPrime(counter))
        i++;
}
Helper.println(counter);
```

It is returning `104033` but the correct answer is `104743`. Where is my problem?

Comment: Debugger! Please learn to use one.

Comment: Can you post the problem? We don't really like following unnecessary external links. What have you done to figure out the error?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with `Helper.isPrime`? Post the code

Comment: Note that you're not counting the first prime, `2`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct answer?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - 104743 is the 10001st prime.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard lets both delete our comments and save the argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have three problems with your code:

1. Your code does not test whether 2 is a prime, so you are missing that in your count. You should initialize `counter` to 0 or 1, not 2.
2. By using `while (i<=10001)`, you are counting until you find 10002 primes. Since you are also not counting 2, you are going two steps past where you need to go. The loop test should be `while (i<10001)`.
3. Since your answer is *lower* than the correct answer (even though your loop went two primes past where it should have stopped), your `Helper.isPrime` method is clearly identifying too many numbers as prime. It will need to be fixed, but since you have not posted the code for it, it's impossible to say what is needed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**correct version**

```
int i=0;
int counter=1; // chnage initial value of counter
while (i<10001){ // change terminating condition
    counter++;
    if (Helper.isPrime(counter))
        i++;
}
Helper.println(counter);
```

**Explanation/Issues with your version**

First solve it for smaller subset, suppose you want to print 3rd prime number.
As per your code

```
i=0, counter  =3, is 3 prime yes i=1
i=1  counter = 4 is 4 prime No i =1
i=1 counter = 5 is 5 prime Yes i=2
i=2 counter =6 is 6 prime No i=2
i=2 counter =7 is 7 prime yes i=3
i=3 counter =8 is 8 prime no i=3
i=3 counter = 9 is 9 prime no i=3
i=3 counter =10 is 10 prime no i=3
i=3 counter =11 is 11 prime yes i=4
loop terminates
ans: 11
```

is 11 2nd prime, No

issues:

1. why counter starting with 2
2. termiating condition of loop, evn if the
       number is found we are not terminating

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: sorry, but if the two issue I mentioned are corrected i.e. counter is started with 1 instead of 2 and terminating condition is changed from i<=10001 to i<10001, the program will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
   int find=10001;
   int counter =1;
   int currentNumber=2;
   while (counter <= find){
       if(Helper.isPrime(currentNumber)){
           counter++;              
       }
       currentNumber++;
   }
    System.out.println(currentNumber-1);
```